# Disable 4.1.1 camera slide effect

Tags: camera, 4.1-jelly-bean

I've noticed since the 4.1.1 update that every time a photo is taken there's this very distracting slide effect that transitions the photo you've just snapped off the screen, replacing it with the live view.

Is there any way to disable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new animation added to Jelly Bean camera app when photos are being taken, acts as a visual hint at a new swipe gesture that's been added.

The idea is to make the user aware that [swiping to the left at any time](http://www.android.com/whatsnew/#jb-photos), they are able to scroll through all the photos taken:

> When taking a photo, a new animation sweeps your photo off the screen. There is now a new paging animation when swiping between photos.

<sup>Android 4.1, Jelly Bean - [Camera and Gallery](http://www.android.com/about/jelly-bean/) (scroll down till this title)</sup>

From that location, the user can rotate, crop, share, just like in the gallery app.

As already mentioned by [jlehenbauer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/26881/16265), it's a feature and cannot be removed.

---

Here a YouTube video about this: [Android 4.1 Jelly Bean Camera app](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=umta7NfglAA)

Answer (score 6):

I believe this is a "feature" of the new Jelly Bean camera. You probably **won't** be able to change it without resorting to using another camera app (like [Camera Zoom FX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=slide.cameraZoom&hl=en)) or installing a custom ROM.